# Is it legitimate to combine two scales of interest on different topics to one based on the intervention condition?

Tags: regression, interaction, scales, scale-construction

I am doing research where we study students' motivation when working on physics learning tasks. In doing so, we give students learning tasks that are motivated by different contexts, so that they either complete the task in a biological context (such as nutrition or photosynthesis) or in an technological context (such as motors or solar cells). Among other control variables, we also asked about interest in biology and technology to predict motivation.

Since we assume that interest in biology or technology is only crucial if the task is contextualized in the corresponding area, the question is whether, based on the condition of which context (biology or technology) is present, one may combine the two scales of interest in biology and technology (after z-standardizing) into one "interest of context area." This would eliminate messy interactions in the regression model.

So instead of

Motivation <- ... + b1*interest biology + b2*interest biology*context + b3*interest technology+ b4*interest technology*context.

I would have

Motivation <- ... + b1*interest in context area